# Redirect STDOUT to a file while process is waiting for user input

Tags: perl, stdin

I am trying to redirect the `STDOUT` and `STDERR` into a log file, but I also want to print those streams to the console. I am using Perl, and my code looks like this:

```
use Capture::Tiny ':all';

my $stderr, $stdout;

($stdout, $stderr) = capture {
    system($command);
};

print $stdout;
print $stderr;
```

It works, but if the command waits for a user input, the program doesn't print `$stdout` to `STDOUT` until a key is pressed. Is there any way to print `$stdout` to `STDOUT` before it needs user input? Line by line approach would be fine.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simple approach that I could think of:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

# Using perl one liner as a command here
# which prints a string to STDOUT and STDERR
my $cmd = "perl -e 'print STDOUT \"stdout\n\"; print STDERR \"stderr\n\";'";

my $log = "./test.log";

# using "2>&1" we are redirecting stderr also to stdout
system("$cmd 2>&1 | tee $log");

# Sample run results in both the strings getting printed to console as well as to log file
> perl test.pl
stderr 
stdout

> cat test.log 
stderr
stdout
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using the tee and it works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not familiar with `Capture::Tiny` so this may not be entirely relevant - generally though, if I'm looking to handle `STDIN`, `STDOUT` and/or `STDERR` then I look towards either `open` (if it's just one), or [`IPC::Open2`](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open2.html) and [`IPC::Open3][1]` which open multiple file descriptors attached to a process.

```
use IPC::Open3;
$pid = open3(\*CHLD_IN, \*CHLD_OUT, \*CHLD_ERR,
                'some cmd and args', 'optarg', ...);

use IPC::Open2;
$pid = open2(\*CHLD_OUT, \*CHLD_IN, 'some', 'cmd', 'and', 'args');
```

Although I would suggest rather than the examples - you can use lexical filehandles:

```
my($chld_out, $chld_in);
$pid = open2($chld_out, $chld_in, 'some cmd and args');
```

You can then read and write from your filehandles (bear in mind though - by default a read will be blocking).

You do need to `close` and then (ideally) `waitpid` to clear up the process when you're done though.

Comment: Thank you. I have chosen the tee solution, because it needs a lot less effort.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Capture::Tiny's `tee`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny#tee) instead of `capture`.

> The `tee` function works just like `capture`, except that output is captured as well as passed on to the original `STDOUT` and `STDERR`.

Just replace the function call and your output will end up both in the variables and on the screen.

```
use Capture::Tiny ':all';

my $stderr, $stdout;

($stdout, $stderr) = tee {
    system($command);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, the tee works fine. :) I hope there is an alternative for Windows too.

Comment: @ToMmY_hun doesn't it work on Windows? I don't have one to test it right now, butt he doc says it should.

Comment: I do not know yet. I'll tell you if I started to use it.